# Handling Errors in Zend View Helpers

Tags: zend-framework, error-handling

When I throw an exception in a View Helper it is not caught by the ErrorController.  (I get an ugly message about an uncaught exception.)

I read somewhere that the ErrorController doesn't catch errors in Plugins.  Does the same apply to View Helpers?

What's the best strategy for handing exceptions in a View Helper?

Thanks!

Comment: You're view shouldn't be processing data, just displaying it. You should do all your data handling in the controller.

Comment: @Ashley the data passed to the view could be incorrect, so a view helper which expects a certain type of data could still possibly throw an exception if the data passed to it is invalid. So I would say there's no reason why an exception couldn't occur in a view.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that errors are handled by ErrorHandler plugin. So if any error occur, iit HAS to occur AFTER the errorHandler call. So if any of your plugins fail earlier then errorHandler is registred, it won't work. There is no other exception to errorHandler's functionality AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

For the reason of why it's not being caught to the error controller, I'm not 100% sure, but this is my best guess without looking into it more:

Views are rendered from the ViewRenderer plugin, or the Zend_Layout plugin if it's a layout, so this could be why you're getting the error message - as you said, exceptions thrown from plugins don't get properly caught into the error controller.

You probably should consider errors in views to be programming errors, so you could just throw up a generic "application error" type of error message. You could achieve this through using set_error_handler/set_exception_handler